# MySQLNonTransientConnectionException/jdbc4.CommunicationsException Errors Continuing while using C3P0

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jdbc, c3p0

I am running a Java web application using Hibernate and C3P0 as the connection pool, MySQL 5.6 database. I am continuing to run into issues on the deployed applications where the connections are timing out and generating errors:

> Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: The last packet successfully
>   received from the server was 426,126,080 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to
>   the server was 426,126,081 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured value of
>   'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before
>   use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using
>   the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.

In particular, any period of inactivity will cause errors to start occurring. A long period caused errors such as these:

> (DefaultConnectionTester.java:148) [http-nio-8080-exec-9]: SQL State '08007' of Exception tested
>   by statusOnException() implies that the database is invalid, and the pool should refill itself
>   with fresh Connections. com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException:
>   Communications link failure during commit(). Transaction resolution unknown.

and

> (C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:981) [http-nio-8080-exec-9]: A ConnectionTest has failed,
>   reporting that all previously acquired Connections are likely invalid. The pool will be reset.

Hibernate/C3P0 connection params are:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.initial_pool_size">5</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">50</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">5</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">500</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">1800</property> <!-- in secs -->
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">480</property> <!-- in secs -->
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout">false</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckin">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.preferredTestQuery">select 1</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.maxConnectionAge">3600</property> <!-- in secs -->
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.numHelperThreads">8</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.maxIdleTimeExcessConnections">600</property>
```

I have tried repeatedly to adjust the C3P0 parameters based on other comments on this topic and on the C3P0 docs, to no avail. The web application goes through periods of inactivity and heavy use, surely there must be some guidance on how the connection pooling should be configured in this use case, but I have yet to find any that have made a dent in this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the values of testConnectionOnCheckout to:

```
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout">true</property>
```

Imagine this scenario (with your current configuration):

- you have one connection in the pool which has just expired
- the thread that checks idle connection every 480 seconds hasn't kicked in yet
- a user goes to the website... the connection is picked up from the pool and you get an exception the first time you try to use it, as it was expired and C3P0 didn't test the connection on checkout.

The other thing you **must** do is to check the timeout configured in mysql. If the timeout is configured to be 60 seconds, and you check the connection every 480 seconds... then all your connections will definitely be closed. As a good rule of thumb, the idle test period should be around 1/2 to 3/4 of the timeout configured in the DB, to ensure that the connections are kept open.

You also need to take into account firewalls that are in the middle, as they might close the connection sooner if they see no traffic.

Comment: I have tried setting the testConnectionOnCheckout to true, it didn't seem to have any effect. The MySQL timeout is the default of 28800 seconds.

Comment: What network devices do you have between your web container and the DB server? Does any of those do TCP/IP filtering (such as a firewall).

Comment: No firewalls -- both systems are on the same network inside the firewall.